# Incorporating a Windows Mobile, a Silverlight and a Web project under a common DAL (Ria Services)

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, windows-mobile, data-access-layer, wcf-ria-services

I am in the beginning of my thesis, and I have to implement a solution about aggregating reports, obtained by a Windows Mobile application, to a central storage. Then, the available data are going to be presented through an Entity Framework model, using RIA services as a data access layer, for the Silverlight project. Can I utilize the RIA services, for the windows mobile communication? How can I persist business objects at the windows mobile application, through the same DAL? Is it possible, or should I simply write explicitly the appropriate methods for the mobile side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can; depending on your DAL, it may or may not be able to serialise to a compatibile format on all devices. Assuming it can't, you can always translate them into 'Portable' objects pretty easily.